# Taking actions on a new record in the data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there any way to detect/act on a new record entry in a specific data extension (launch a script or automation for instance) without the usage of Journey Builder functionalities.

My alternative way of doing this is to perform batching operations on a schedule but this is not ideal obviously (automation studio).

Comment: Do you need this in real time or is a delay of 1 hour acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No. You can't detect new records in a data extension in real time. Depending on the origin of your data, you might have few options:

1. Using [Smart Capture JB Entry Event](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_use_a_smart_capture_form_as_a_journey_builder_entry_event.htm&type=5) - which will inject your subscriber to the journey, once the Smart Capture form is submitted
2. Using [File Drop Trigger](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_triggered_automations.htm&type=5) Automation - starting an automation once a file is uploaded to Enhanced FTP. You can use this automation to [trigger your journey](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_data_extension.htm&type=5)
3. If your data originates from Sales/Service cloud, you can use the [Salesforce Data Event](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5) to inject lead or contact into the journey.